# Getting Bluetooth to work on Windows 10 and C++Builder

Tags: bluetooth, c++builder

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth device on my Windows 10 machine, but nothing is showing up. Not with BT classic or LE. Has anyone managed to get this working?

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::DiscoverClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Bluetooth1->DiscoverDevices(5000);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
//{
//    BluetoothLE1->DiscoverServices(BluetoothLE1->DiscoveredDevices->Items[ListBox1->ItemIndex]);
//}
    
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//void __fastcall TForm1::BluetoothLE1EndDiscoverServices(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothGattServiceList * const AServiceList)
//{
//    int i;
//    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//        ListBox2->Items->Add(AServiceList->Items[i]->UUIDName);
//    }
//}
    
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Bluetooth1DiscoveryEnd(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothDeviceList * const ADeviceList)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ADeviceList->Count; i++) {
        ListBox1->Items->Add(ADeviceList->Items[i]->DeviceName);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That would be great if you can explain what you want to do. Bu tany way, VCL Bluetooth implementation is no good. Try out thrid party library. Bluetooth  Framework or 32feet or IPWorks.

Comment: Did you verify that Bluetooth is installed and working properly in Windows itself? Can you connect to Bluetooth devices from outside of your code?

Comment: I canquery the device now (manual mac addr) i'm using this code with the correct service and charachteristic but don't know how to get the HR value out of it, any suggestions?  auto leDevice = co_await Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(mac);auto n = leDevice->Name;
 auto servicesResult = co_await leDevice->GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceUUID);
 auto service = servicesResult->Services->GetAt(0);
 auto characteristicsResult = co_await service->GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(characteristicUUID);
 auto characteristic = characteristicsResult->Characteristics->GetAt(0);